# What does "Irq14=4096" do in System.ini

Tags: hard-drive, speed

I found the article ["Increase Speed of Harddisk"](http://nicpak.blogspot.de/2012/03/increase-speed-of-hard-disk.html) and it says that you have to add the line `Irq14=4096` after `[386Enh]` in the [System.ini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYSTEM.INI) file to increase your hard disc speed.

Many people have tested it, so I just want to know what is this line and what will this do?

Comment: If you downvote, please leave a comment how to improve the question. I see nothing wrong in its current state.

Comment: My guess would be is that it's because it shows a lack of research effort, and additionally its got grammar issues. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IRQ 14 is the [IRQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_request) assigned to "Primary hard drive (Hard Drive Controller)".
Adding `Irq14=4096` in a system.ini would result in a 4 MB buffer for IRQ requests from this device to your CPU.

But its only relevant for old 16-bit programs as the previous answer already stated.

> Computers running Windows NT 4.0, 2000, XP, or later operating systems no longer have a system.ini. Instead of storing these settings in the system.ini recent version of Windows stores settings in the system registry. For backwards compatibility, Windows 2000 and Windows XP may have a very basic or blank system.ini file.

<sup>[Source](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/systemin.htm)</sup>

I tent to agree @techie007 that this is a myth.

Answer (score 4):

It's a Myth, the command does nothing.

And even if it did do anything, it would only effect 16-bit Windows programs (since that's what System.ini is for -- compatibility with old 16-bit Windows apps).

But if you really want to confirm for yourself, benchmark your drives, then set that setting and then benchmark again.

[a source](http://home.comcast.net/~supportcd/XPMyths.html)